# who retweeted a tweet

Tags: php, web-services, twitter

how do i find who retweeted a certain tweet?

The show status api call returns data on a certain tweet, according to ID, though does not show who retweeted (if retweeted)
http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/:id

There's just a numerical 'retweet_count' field. I'm looking for user ID \ screen_name of the retweeters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [GET statuses/:id/retweeted_by](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/%3aid/retweeted_by) API method.